# What does the `type` word do?

Tags: forth, gforth

Given the following function, (borrowed from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server#Forth))

```
: (echo) ( sock buf -- sock buf )
  begin
    cr ." waiting..."
    2dup 2dup size read-socket nip
    dup 0>
  while
    ."  got: " 2dup type ( <-- HERE )
    rot write-socket
  repeat
  drop drop drop ;
```

What does `type` do in,

```
."  got: " 2dup type
```

Comment: Did you look in the [gforth manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/gforth-0.7.0.pdf)?

Comment: @lurker yep, link below. It was a self-answered question because the word "type" is so vague it was more difficult to find then I felt it needed to be. (try to spam google for the greater good here)

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realize that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`type` is a *word*](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Displaying-characters-and-strings.html#index-type-_0040var_007b-c_002daddr-u-_002d_002d---_007d--core-2016). You can find the list of the words [here](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Word-Index.html)

> ```
> type       c-addr u –         core       “type”
> ```
>
> If u>0, display u characters from a string starting with the character stored at c-addr.

In this case you have

```
128 constant size
create buf size allot
```

Then you set `buf` with `read-socket`. This `type` it to a string and prints it out.

Returns a memory address for the string and the size.

```
cr s" foo bar " .s
```

Output:

```
<2> 94085808947584 8  ok
```

Here we provide the memory address and size to `type` and get "foo bar"

```
cr 94085808947584 8 type
```

Output:

```
foo bar  ok
```